# When i call a spring bean in @ManagedProperty(value="springBeanName") is created new instance or uses the current one of applicationContext.xml?

Tags: spring, jsf

In a @ManagedBean annotated class when i have a field that is

```
@ManagedProperty(value="springBean") 
SpringBean springBean;
```

when the managedBean is created then managedProperty springBean refers to the bean in applicationContext.xml or it creates a new instance.

Comment: What exactly have you observed yourself? Was the actual behavior expected or unexpected?

Comment: BalusC well i think of that there is not created new one cuz and is used the one initialised in the beginning of application.

Comment: That's expected behavior, right? Why exactly this question then?

Comment: I wasn't sure about this because integrating spring with jsf is not pure spring mvc or pure jsf.